# How to accept console input at the Elance RUBY Programming Skills Test

Tags: ruby

I tried to test my ruby skills using the elance "RUBY Programming Skills Test". I couldn't figure out a way for it to accept my answers when console input was given. The code below works using ruby 1.9.3, but it is not accepted by the testing software.

> Problem Text :
>
> Write a program which will accept three sentences (one sentence per
>   line) and print the words having Initial Caps within the sentences.
>   Below is an example.
>
> Here is an example. If the below three sentences are given to the
>   program as input,
>
> This is a Program Coding test
>
> of Initial Caps
>
> the program Will Test You
>
> Then, the output would look like:
>
> This
>
> Program
>
> Coding
>
> Initial
>
> Caps
>
> Will
>
> Test
>
> You
>
> Note: In case of input data being supplied to the question, it should
>   be assumed to be a console input.

My solution:

```
a=gets[0..-2]
b=gets[0..-2]
c=gets[0..-2]
d=(a + ' ' + b + ' ' + c).chomp
d.split(' ').each do |e|
    puts e[0].capitalize + e[1..-1]
end
```

Is there a problem with my code? Are there alternative solutions that may be accepted? Any other ideas?

Comment: Does it give you any hint on why it fails? Have you had other programs running on elance which used `gets`?

Comment: No hint at all. In a previous exercise gets and stdin are recommended. But I failed at that exercise too.